# php retrieve value from response

Tags: php

I`m trying to find a way to use the retrieved values I receive from my SMS Messaging Provider, the values I receive is:

```
    0|IN_PROGRESS|225161649
```

Where I need to store certain values in my database.

Here is a url to where I receive my values:

```
    http://bulksms.2way.co.za:5567/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0?username=xxxx&password=xxxxx&message=Hi+Mom+%26+Dad&msisdn=44423456789
```

This will return values:

```
    23|invalid credentials (username was: xxxx)|
```

Now I need to get the values and store in PHP variable to process to my database.

Here is my form that submits the data:

```
       $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $text = $_POST['textcounter'];
        $username = 'xxxx';
        $password = 'xxxx';

        // Set Timezone
        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg');
        $date = date("m/d/y G.i:s", time());

        // Create Unique ID
        $code = md5(time());
        $newid = $code.$clientid;

        $sql="INSERT INTO sms_sent (sent_id, sent_message, sent_date, sent_quantity, client_id, sent_mobile)VALUES('$newid', '$text', '$date', '1', '$clientid', '$mobile')";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

$url = "http://bulksms.2way.co.za/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0"; // URL to calc.cgi
        $fields = array(
        'site'=>'',
        'username'=>($username),
        'password'=>($password),
        'message'=>urlencode($text),
        'msisdn'=>urlencode($mobile)

                        );
        $fields_string="?";
        //url-ify the data for the POST
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
        rtrim($fields_string,'&');

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

        //execute post
        ob_start();
        curl_exec($ch);
        ob_end_clean();
        echo '<div class="alert alert-block alert-success">
                                      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
                                      <h4 class="alert-heading">Success!</h4>
                                      Your message has been Sent!
                                    </div><br/><br/><a href="search_contact.php" class="btn btn-large btn-round">Search Contact</a>';

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Have you got some code that does the HTTP request (cURL?) and you want to parse the response, or do you have nothing?

Comment: What does the second string have to do with the first? `$values = explode('|' file_get_contents('http://..........'));`

Comment: Second string is to show response from submitted http url

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function

```
<?php
    $responseParams=explode("|",response);
    foreach($responseParams as $params)
    {

    echo $params;

    }
?>
```

Further reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
rtrim($fields_string,'&');
```

rtrim Returns String and does NOT modify arguments.